# «Тем не менее прежде чем начать». Нужна ли запятая между союзами?

Tags: союзы

> Тем не менее прежде чем начать, позвольте откланяться...

Надо ли разделять два союза запятыми? Понятно, что "тем не менее" не терпит после себя запятой, но как быть со стыком союзов?

Comment: Прежде, чем начать, перо нужно расписать.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь возможен авторский выбор, но вариант **с обособлением** предпочтителен, так как более удобен для прочтения. Более того, для частицы  ***тем не менее,*** состоящей из трех слов,  он представляется практически однозначным, особенно в сочетании со сложным союзом (***тем не менее, прежде чем***):

(1) Интонационное выделение частицы: ***Тем не мЕнее,  прежде чем начАть, позвольте откланяться...***

(2 ) Нет интонационного выделения частицы: ***Тем не менее прежде чем начАть, позвольте откланяться...***

Официально можно сослаться на Грамоту.ру, которая для частицы ***тем не менее*** допускает обособление **в общем случае**, об этом же говорит в своих правилах и Розенталь.

Что касается **особого правила** у Розенталя на эту тему (обособление частиц перед подчинительным союзом в частных случаях), то я не уверена, что его можно найти.

Да и нужно ли такое правило, вроде бы ситуация понятна. Обычно частицы относятся к подчинительному союзу, но при интонационном выделении могут быть обособлены, как и вводные слова.  Что касается конкретного сочетания *тем не менее, прежде чем*, то его в большинстве случаев вообще сложно прочитать без интонационного выделения частицы.

**Примечание** (об интонационном выделении при обособлении)

У нас есть **две причины** для интонационного обособления – фонетическая и смысловая.  (1) **Фонетическое обособление**.  В этом случае необходимость обособления задается однозначно – структурой предложения, которое иначе сложно прочитать. (2) **Смысловое обособление**. В других случаях разные варианты прочтения возможны,  и тогда автор может интонационно подчеркнуть  нужное слово.  Необходимость такого подчеркивания обычно следует из контекста.

**Дополнительная информация**

1. Отсутствие обособления возможно для малораспространенных придаточных,  как в приведенном примере,  в противном случае  запятая ставится. Это можно проверить по **Нацкорпусу** для сочетаний  *тем не менее когда,  тем не менее если*, даже там обособления нет **в редких случаях.**

***Тем не менее, когда** я попал в опалу, он меня, к моему удивлению, не покинул, навещал регулярно и в любой момент проявлял готовность помочь*. [Владимир Войнович. (1999)]

2. По поводу утверждения:  *Понятно, что ***тем не менее*** не терпит после себя запятой.*

Образно говоря, этой частице с уступительным значением приходится иногда "терпеть" обособление. Этот вариант менее частотный, но используется не так уж редко.  Причина одна – авторское интонационное выделение, например: *Тем не менее, проблемы у славистов есть*. [Сергей Довлатов., 1990]

3. Надо сказать, что иногда и  Грамоте.ру **приходится «сдавать» свои позиции** по  поводу невозможности обособления ***тем не менее***, заявленной в Справочнике.

**Вопрос № 235549.**   Скажите, пожалуйста, является ли "тем не менее" вводным словом? обособляется ли?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Слово ***тем не менее***  обычно не обособляется, однако иногда его выделяют как **вводное слово** при соответствующей интонации.
[http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s="тем%20не%20менее](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%22%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5)

Эту же тему раскрывает **Розенталь**, когда говорит об обособлении частиц в общем случае (примечание к П.8)  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Пунктуационное выделение этих слов (= частиц)  в некоторых текстах объясняется **разными причинами**: в одних случаях сказывается то обстоятельство, что некоторые из приведенных слов относятся **к так называемым модальным частицам, близким к модальным (вводным) словам;** в других — играют роль смысловые оттенки, присущие отдельным словам и допускающие их выделение запятыми; наконец, возможно влияние прежних правил или индивидуальной **авторской пунктуации.**

Comment: Sharon, прочитайте и здесь. http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.43

Comment: Кстати, этот вопрос уже не раз задавался на нашем форуме. И вы тоже задавали и отвечали.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, что напомнили.  У меня с информационным пространством сложные отношения, надо хотя бы два раза  вернуться к одной теме. Теперь уж точно запомню.